# Error al pasarle una clase propia al método onBindViewHolder

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Resulta que en el método `onBindViewHolder` me pide por parámetros dos variables, una de tipo `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` y un entero.

El tema, es que yo le quiero pasar por parámetro una instancia de la clase que he creado arriba, pero al hacerlo me salta un error que dice lo siguiente:

> method does not override method from its superclass

El problema es que no entiendo por qué se produce ese error de compilación si mi clase `ViewHolder` extiende de `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` y al final es lo que me está pidiendo que le pase.

```
public class EntradasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<String> titles;
    ArrayList<String> texts;
    ArrayList<Integer> images;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public int currentItem;
        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView itemTitle;
        public TextView itemText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carditem_image);
            itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carditem_title);
            itemText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carditem_text);

            titles = new ArrayList<>();
            texts = new ArrayList<>();
            images = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                titles.add("Entrada " + i);
                texts.add("Texto " + i);
                images.add(R.drawable.defaultitem);
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item" + position, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_entrada, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }



    @Override //method does not override method from its superclass
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta?, tiene que ser en español porqu estas en **SO en Español**

Comment: Lo siento, es la primera vez que utilizo esta página. Resulta que en el método onBindViewHolder me pide por parámetros dos variables, una de tipo RecyclerView.ViewHolder y un entero. El tema, es que yo le quiero pasar por parámetro una instancia de la clase que he creado arriba, pero al hacerlo me salta un error que dice lo siguiente: //method does not override method from its superclass. El problema es que no entiendo por qué se produce ese error de compilación si mi clase ViewHolder extiende de RecyclerView.ViewHolder y al final es lo que me está pidiendo que le pase.

Comment: Hola Alejandro Suárez. Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial es el español por lo que has de traducir la pregunta, pulsando en [edit], para que sea aceptada. Tambien mira [ask]  y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Ya está editada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es que estas creando de manera incorrecta tu `RecyclerView`
Si estas usando una clase dentro te tu clase debes llamarla de la siguiente forma:

```
public class EntradasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EntradasAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

Es es nombre de la clase donde se encuentra el `ViewHolder` seguido del nombre de tu clase en este caso se llama `ViewHolder`, por lo cual quedaría de la forma en que te mostre.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Sin embargo ahora me ha surgido otro problema, pues al ejecutar el método getItemCount() me salta un nullPointerException.Pienso que esto es por que este método se ejecuta antes de instanciar la clase de ViewHolder y por lo tanto antes de rellenar los ArrayList. De todas formas no se muy bien cómo solucionarlo...

Comment: Bien eso es porque no has instanciado tus ArrayList, normarmente se hace un constructor para llenar esos arreglos, por ejemplo public `EntradasAdapter(ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> texts, ArrayList<String> images)`

Comment: Te recomiendo leer un poco en la documentacion oficial [Crear Listas,https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419]